# Error: "ts-node/esm/transpile-only 'resolve'" did not call the next hook in its chain and did

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, appium, webdriver-io

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Getting this error when run the test using npx wdio command.

How to resolve this issue.
Error: "ts-node/esm/transpile-only 'resolve'" did not call the next hook in its chain and did not explicitly signal a short circuit. If this is intentional, include `shortCircuit: true` in the hook's return.

Comment: it's better to post code here instead of a screenshot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way to get this running is to add typescript and ts-node to the project.

```
npm i -D typescript ts-node
```

Then `npx wdio`

I opted not to use the compiler in a WebdriverIO project but then started getting this error after a few weeks. I just added the libraries above rather than try to chase down the config i likely messed up, in order to eliminate the error message.

Answer (score 1):

This error started to occur from node version >= 16.17.0 due to some changes in the Experimental ESM Loader Hooks API.

Solution to resolve this error:

1. Downgrade the node version to 16.16.0 and you will not see this error.
2. Since you were using appium v2.x with wdio javascript, install dependency `ts-node` by running the following command:

```
npm install ts-node --save-dev
```

**Reason**

`Appium v1.x` does not support TypeScript natively, and therefore it does not use the `tsconfig.json` file. Appium v1.x is based on Node.js, which supports JavaScript natively but does not include TypeScript support out of the box.

`Appium v2.x` will have better TypeScript support out of the box. The new version of Appium is based on the WebDriver protocol and will be implemented in TypeScript. This means that developers will be able to write tests in TypeScript without having to set up a separate TypeScript compiler or configure TypeScript manually. Using `TypeScript` and `tsconfig` in `Appium 2.0` brings several benefits, such as better code maintainability and error checking, improved code readability, and better tooling support.

**Important Note**

This error will not occur if you use `Appium v1.x` with latest node version (>16.16.0) in the `wdio`.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I updated my WebdriverIO version from V7 to V8 and got the same error:
[image]

Then I **updated my ts-node version** in `package.json` to V10 and this issue seems to be fixed